# isnumeric function not providing expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The `dsply_val` is a `varchar(2000)` field. When i run the query below i am getting 0 for the `isnumeric` columns even though these values appear to be numeric. I am trying to perform a simple calculation on this column but I end up getting conversion error when I try to convert to `decimal` or `float`. As you can see by the `15.2` value some actually do come back as numeric.

I exported the `dsply_val` to excel and verified that there are no letters or anything out of the ordinary.

What else could i attempt with this or what am I not doing correctly?

```
SELECT obsv_cd_name, 
       dsply_val,
       ISNUMERIC(dsply_val),
       ISNUMERIC(dsply_val + 'e0'),
       ISNUMERIC(rtrim(Ltrim(dsply_val)))
FROM smsmir.mir_sr_obsv
where obsv_cd_name = 'WBC' 
and sort_dtime >= '2015-01-25' 
and orgz_cd = 'CFVMC'
and dsply_val NOT like ('%SEE%') 

WBC 8.6     0   0   0
WBC 7.8     0   0   0
WBC 13.4    0   0   0
WBC 5.9     0   0   0
WBC 8.2     0   0   0
WBC 5.9     0   0   0
WBC 7.5     0   0   0

WBC 15.2    1   1   1
WBC 15.2    0   0   0
```

Comment: And the database engine is?

Comment: MS SQL 2008 my apologies.

Comment: for one of 15.2 it is 1 and for another one is 0 ?

Comment: What convert error do you get? Seems like there could be an "invisble" character at the end of the number.

Comment: I do not receive an error with this query. I just do not get the results I expect. For one 15.2 it is 1 and for the other it is 0. Any invisible characters i would imagine would be taken care of by the ltrim and rtrim?

Comment: The error comes when i try to use that field in a calculation like "case when dsply_val >= 12 then 1 else 0 end" then I get the error Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5.7
' to data type int.

Comment: To your last post (showing the conversion error )5.7 is not an integer. Regarding the OP, something is clearly getting lost in the data that has posted above. Can you send the DDL for mir_sr_obsv and sample data causing the inconsistent results?

Comment: use 'case when convert(decimal,dsply_val) >= 12 then 1 else 0 end'

Comment: Initially all this started when i tried 'case when convert(decimal,dsply_val) >= 12 then 1 else 0 end' and would receive 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.' Then I began troubleshooting with the ISNUMERIC function.

Comment: Have you tried concatenating something to the value to see if anything weird comes back?
    '\*' + dsply_val + '\*'
and get the results back as text, not as a grid so that any weird formatting doesn't get lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have line feed or carriage return or tab char in your column.
Actually I can reproduce your problem:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
```

Set string to 6 + Carriage Return + Line Feed + Tab

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX)  = '6' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(9)
```

You see just 6

```
SELECT @s
```

But the length of string is 4:

```
SELECT LEN(@s)
```

Here are results for ISNUMERIC function:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(@s)
```

Even TRIM doesn't help:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM(@s)))
```

You should replace those chars:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@s, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), ''))
```

You can print out all chars in your string, so you can then replace non-digit chars in string with blank '':

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1
WHILE @i <=  len(@s)
BEGIN
    PRINT ASCII(SUBSTRING(@s, @i, 1))
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you everyone very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function instead of `ISNUMERIC`. `Trim` functionality has been added in the function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.isReallyNumeric  
(  
    @num VARCHAR(64)  
)  
RETURNS BIT  
BEGIN  

    SET @num = LTRIM(RTRIM(@num))

    IF LEFT(@num, 1) = '-'  
        SET @num = SUBSTRING(@num, 2, LEN(@num))  

    DECLARE @pos TINYINT  

    SET @pos = 1 + LEN(@num) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@num))  

    RETURN CASE  
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', @num) = 0  
        AND @num NOT IN ('.', '-', '+', '^') 
        AND LEN(@num)>0  
        AND @num NOT LIKE '%-%' 
        AND  
        (  
            ((@pos = LEN(@num)+1)  
            OR @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @num))  
        )  
    THEN  
        1  
    ELSE  
    0  
    END  
END  
GO
```

And use the query

```
SELECT ColumnName
FROM Yourtable
WHERE DBO.isReallyNumeric(ColumnName)=1
```